# How to import Classes to other files

Tags: javascript, import

I have a paddle.js file that exports the Paddle class by. 
`export default class Paddle` 
I then imported it to my index.js with  `import Paddle from './paddle.js';`

Yet for some reason none of my methods from paddle.js can be used in my index.js. Can someone tell me if my exports or imports are written incorrectly?

Comment: can you show the files and the code so we can understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you instantiated the Paddle class using something like so?

```js
import Paddle from './paddle.js';

const paddle = new Paddle();
paddle.someMethod();
```

Answer (score 0):

An HTML file will not allow you to import a js / react class like that.

`index.html` file will use the `<script>` tag to add javascript.

p.s.

If you're using react, the react's `app.js` or `index.js` inside `src/` will be responsible for putting all the generated html / js in your `public/index.html` file by doing this:

```
ReactDOM.render(<YourComponent />, document.getElementById("root")); 
// where root is id of an element in your index.html file
```

Answer (score 0):

If the function in Paddle.js is static, you can call it as following:

```
Paddle.func();
```

If the function in Paddle.js is not static, you will need an object of Paddle class to call some methods:

```
const paddle = new Paddle();
paddle.func();
```